# How to push a paired key value to all properties named same thing?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
      "prerequisites": [
        "مدل سازی",
        "دینامیک",
        "استاتیک"
      ],
      "targets": [
        "دانشجویان هوافضا",
        "دانشجویان مکانیک",
        "دانشجویان عمران",
        "دانشجویان مهندسی دریا"
      ],
      "sections": [
        {
          "title": "چگونه آباکوس را نصب کنیم.",
          "achievements": [
            "چگونه کامپیوتر را روشن کنیم",
            "چگونه آباکوس را نصب کنیم",
            "چگونه آباکوس را باز کنیم."
          ],
          "lectures": [
                {
                    "title": "آموزش روشن کردن ویندوز",
                    "media": "آدرس فایل pdf  یا ویدیو"
                },
                {
                    "title": "آموزش روشن کردن ویندوز",
                    "media": "آدرس فایل pdf  یا ویدیو"
                }
            ]
        }
      ]
}
```

As you see I have a sections property and in each section, I have a lecture s array,
I want to push paired key, value `{"unlock_users": 0}` to all element of lectures array in TypeScript, How can I do this in TypeScript (angular 5).
I have tested the following code to find the index and and push by index but it returns undefined for index:

```
for (const {section, index_s} of this.data['sections'].map((item, index) => ({ item, index }))) {
  console.log(section);
  console.log(index_s);
   for (const {lecture, index_l} of section['lectures']map((item, index) => ({ item, index }))) {
     console.log(lecture);
     this.data['sections'][index_s]['lectures'][index_l]['unlock_users'] = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `Array.prototype.map` like below:

```js
let json = `{
      "prerequisites": [
        "مدل سازی",
        "دینامیک",
        "استاتیک"
      ],
      "targets": [
        "دانشجویان هوافضا",
        "دانشجویان مکانیک",
        "دانشجویان عمران",
        "دانشجویان مهندسی دریا"
      ],
      "sections": [
        {
          "title": "چگونه آباکوس را نصب کنیم.",
          "achievements": [
            "چگونه کامپیوتر را روشن کنیم",
            "چگونه آباکوس را نصب کنیم",
            "چگونه آباکوس را باز کنیم."
          ],
          "lectures": [
                {
                    "title": "آموزش روشن کردن ویندوز",
                    "media": "آدرس فایل pdf  یا ویدیو"
                },
                {
                    "title": "آموزش روشن کردن ویندوز",
                    "media": "آدرس فایل pdf  یا ویدیو"
                }
            ]
        }  
      ]
}`;
let o = JSON.parse(json);
o.sections = o.sections.map(obj => {
  obj.lectures = obj.lectures.map(lec => {
    lec.unlock_users = 0;
    return lec;
  });
  return obj
});
console.log(o.sections);
```